# Adding content dynamically to sliding drawer throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, slidingdrawer, sliding

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //    requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout d= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_content); 
    final LayoutInflater  inflate=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView tv = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setText("Appointments");
    Log.i("before", "add");
    d.addView(tv);
    Log.i("after", "add");
}
```

I have been trying to add content dynamically in my sliding drawer, but it seems to give me a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: how do i get the line number? :p

Comment: your exception shows it.

Answer (score 0):

use debugger and add break point then u can see line by line execution by pressing F6

Comment: While using the debugger is an extremely useful technique, I think this is more appropriate for an "in general" comment than a direct answer. Could you be more specific in what the user should be looking for?

Comment: didn't understand what u want to say